# ColumnTransformer in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I have an Entity which I use the `ColumnTransformer` for bind and extract values:

```
@Entity
class BPoint {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ColumnTransformer(read = "astext(shape)", write = "toshape(?)")
    private Shape shape;

}
```

And the dao:

```
class BPointDao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Page<BPoint> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("from BPoint");
        List<BPoint> r = q.getResultList();
        int total = em.createQuery("select count(*)  from BPoint").getFirstResult();
        return new PageImpl(r, pageable, total);
    }
    @Override
    public Integer save(BPoint hbds) {
        em.persist(hbds);
        return hbds.getId();
    }
}
```

It works, however once I have to do some query which need the use the sql functions, I meet some problems, take this valid native sql for example:

```
select * from BPoint h where inside(h.shape, 100) = 1;
```

First I tried to use the hql like this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select astext(shape) from BPoint h where inside(h.shape, ?) = 1");
```

However I found that the generated sql contains things like

`...... where inside(astext(h.shape),100).....`

It seems that the `ColumnTransformer read` value is used in the sql function `inside` which is not expected.

So I tried to use the native sql query like this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from BPoint h where inside(h.shape, ? = 1");
```

Not the sql can be executed, but the result cannot be mapped correctly.

Then I have to add the `select fileds` manualy like this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select id,astext(shape) from BPoint h where inside(h.shape, ? = 1");
```

But how about if my Entity have a lot of fileds say it is more than 20?  And how about if some columns name changed?

Is there an alternative method to meet my requirement?

Comment: Why don't you try with executing native sql and and mapping result using `ResultTransformer`

Comment: I am using the native sql at the moment, however I have to calculate the fileds in the sql manually since the table contains almost 100+ columns.

Comment: you said native sql can be executed, but the result cannot be mapped correctly.  What if you write a `ResultTransformer` to map it

Answer (score 3):

First try supplying the return type to your native query:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from BPoint h where inside(h.shape, ? = 1", BPoint.clss);
List<BPoint> result = q.getResultList();
```

Or you could try to do it like this:

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
List<BPoint> points = (List<BPoint>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT {h.*} FROM BPoint {h} WHERE inside({h}.shape, ? = 1")
    .addEntity("h", BPoint.class)
.list();
```

The Hibernate specific API allows you to map native query results to Entities.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear, I can not use the `select * ..` in the native query, if so, hibernate can not map the result set to entity because the value of the ColumnTransformer are not used.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom interceptor and "fix" the SQL to replace all "inside(astext(#REF)) as inside(#REF)

You will have to override org.hibernate.Interceptor#onPrepareStatement(String sql). The input argument contains the sql that you could modify as described.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, however it seems that I will do a raw string replacement for the sql in the `onPrepareStatement` which may be not reliable.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid concern. The only way I can think of doing it reliably and in a performant manner is to extend the dialect and create a StandardSQLFunction and override the render method. In this method you will get the string representation and you can do the same modification here. Please check if this can indeed be done for the "inside" function.